# Making two items of different variable types relate

Tags: arrays, string, integer, record, pascal

I have a record array called election (of index number size 4) that contains about 6 different field names, two of which I'll be focusing this question on. Say, that one field name is called totvot (total votes, declared as integer) and the other called nameC ( candidate name,declared as string)  and I want to use an `if` then loop to say:

```
For count := 1 to 4 do
     begin
       if (election[count].totvot>wc)then
         wc:=election[count].nameC;
       end;
```

What I'm doing above is, assuming all four locations in array `election[count].totvot` is populated, I want to then sort all four to find the highest number. For example, if the four locations are populated as such: 2, 3, 5, and 6 then 6 would be the highest number. And six would also be in location four because it is the fourth number. After, now that I've found the highest number, I want to relate the name also found in  location four to that number, hence the line `WC:=election[count].nameC`. Problem is, I declared `WC` (standing for winning candidate) as an integer and `election[count].nameC` as a string type variable. And I don't know what code to use to get the two to relate (not convert integer to string, but relate). Below is the code that I used to declare and initialize the variables I mentioned.

```
Var
 wc,rate,total,choice,count,totgen,totspe,totspo,y,r: integer;
 Election:array[1..4]of Elect;
Begin
 clrscr;
 textcolor(10);
 wc:=0;
  for count:=1 to 4 do
   begin
     Election[count].totvot:=0;
     Election[count].nameC:='';
```

So essentially, I just wanna relate the highest value in the array election[count].totvot to the name of the candidate that has the highest votes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Before posting a question, you should try googling answers to questions like this with terms like, "pascal convert string to integer". This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105073/string-to-integer-conversion-in-pascal-how-to-do-it

Comment: Oh my gosh, thanks so much i never though to google that, although. Im not really clear on the explanation given

Comment: You probably would benefit from reading some online tutorials on pascal and variable/data types. You need to understand what a String is and an Integer, how they are different, and how to convert between the two. You can also google "pascal Val function" and you will likely find more description of the Val function and how it works... what parameters it has and how they affect the output. That will help you better understand the answer to the linked question.

Comment: you see, i dont necessarily want to convert, i want to relate. It is two different things, right ? lol

Comment: You've not explained the problem clearly. Please provide the definition of `election`, and explain how an integer `wc` is supposed to be able to be assigned `election[count].nameC` (of which you've not provided a defintion). I've read your question three times (including the code), and I can't figure out for the life of me what exactly you're trying to do. When you [edit] to explain, remember that we have no idea what you're trying to do, we can't read your mind to fill in the blanks, and that if you want us to help you you'll need to **clearly** explain what you want to do so we can catch up.

Comment: Im really sorry it wasnt clear enough, entirely new to all this. I tried editing the question. if you like, you can take another look. id appreciate it. thanks in advance and sorry about the confustion

Comment: TBH, it's still not very clear what you're trying to do.  It might help if you post more code, like the code where you define `election` and `wc`.

Comment: ...also, you mention this being a school project.  Are you using functions yet?

Comment: Functions,as in F(x)? then yes, other than that, no. I have a really crappy teacher, so im doing most of it on my own.

Comment: I meant as in Pascal functions.  Given this problem, I would write a function to return the winning candidate's name.

Comment: @JeffC this isn't a type conversion question. It's about looking up one value based on another.

Comment: @KaylanAchong function has the same meaning in any programming language (and even in Microsoft Excel). A function is a section of code separated from the main program, and it returns one or more results. Brian's suggestion would make your code neat, but the function would only need to be called once in the problem you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of your array (values of `count`) already relates the each person's name with the number of votes. There are several different solutions to what you wish to do. Much of the skills in coding is deciding which solution you think is best. Here are two examples described. Writing the code is up to you.

1. Create a loop - either a `for`, `while` or `repeat` loop- which goes through the array from `count:=1` to `count:=4` and uses a new variable `winner` to store the number of the person with the highest score - each line of the loop would compare the votes for the winner so far to the next person's vote count, storing only the `count` of the highest winner. 
   Suppose your winning candidate was number 2 in the array (`count:=2`), the winner's name would be `election[2].nameC` and the winning number of votes would be `election[2].totvot`.
2. Immediately before your existing `for` statement add an lines to introduce a new variable, eg *winner* (as above) and set the value to 1. Inside the `for` statement  compare the number of votes for the current candidate `election[count].totvot` to the value of `election[winner].totvot`, if `election[count].totvot` is larger then set `winner:=count` (so winner remains the highest by the end of the loop). Then your winner's name is `election[winner].nameC`.

Both solutions would need minor improvements if joint winners were quite likely (eg small number of total votes cast).

Your question got some down votes - possibly because your explanation was long and a bit hard to follow at times. If you can break a problem down into simple bullet pointed steps it will help and build your programming and problem solving skills as well.

Some Pascal references are hidden away in the wiki of the Pascal question tag may be useful -  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pascal/info

Comment: Stilll a bit unsure about your explaination, but its probably cause im weak in code. Thanks so much for helping, much thanks and appreciation (:

Comment: think of it this way: you are a student in a school. You have a unique student number, and a name, and a total score for your Math test. So do the other students. Anyone's your name and score can be found by looking up their student number. This code is the same: `count`is the candidate number. Candidate 2 means lookup the name & number of votes for count 2. To find the winner, compare all the numbers of votes and write down the winner's candidate number (`count`).  Count 2's name is the winner's name. Count is the `index` for the array-an index lookups everything else in the array, like name

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I can see that an `Elect` has a candidate's name (`nameC`) and the number of votes (`totvot`).  The way you're using `wc` (winning count?) tells me that it's holding a vote total.  Since it's a number type, you can't put a string into it, so you'll have to use something else.  I would add a new variable `winnerName`:

```
Var winnerName: String;
//Initialization code here

For count := 1 to 4 do
    begin
        if (election[count].totvot>wc)then
            wc:=election[count].totvot;
            winnerName:=election[count].nameC;
    end;
```

Comment: i initially thought of that, but i assumed it would be incorrect because election[count].nameC could hold any name from the 4 spaces thanks however. If i merit list, ill mention brian from stack overflow :P

Comment: @KaylanAchong if Brian's answer is helpful to you then clicking the upvote or the tick (for accepted answer) is a way to say thanks on stackoverflow, it increases the person's reputation (the number by their name). Higher reputations let you gain more priviledges on the site.